# how can i get mobile status indicator in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So yea I code in python and I was wondering is it was posible to get mobile status indicator can someone help me please, thank you !

Comment: [Check out their docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.is_on_mobile)

Comment: Have you attempted anything to figure this out?

Comment: @12944qwerty yes i've also been looking in yt and github and everything is about discord.js

Comment: A quick search on the docs gave me the [answer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.is_on_mobile). I'm assuming that google does this same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported for a discord bot if that's what you're asking!

Comment: This is not true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903401/how-do-i-get-mobile-status-for-discord-bot-by-directly-modifying-identify-packet

Answer (score 0):

Edit function in \discord\gateway.py "identify"

`'$browser': 'Discord Android'`