# How do I get mobile status for discord bot by directly modifying IDENTIFY packet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

Apparently, discord bots can have mobile status as opposed to the desktop (online) status that one gets by default.

[image: bot having mobile status]

After a bit of digging I found out that such a status is achieved by modifying the `IDENTIFY packet` in [`discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/45d498c1b76deaf3b394d17ccf56112fa691d160/discord/gateway.py#L370) modifying the value of `$browser` to `Discord Android` or `Discord iOS` should theoretically get us the mobile status.

After modifying code snippets I found online which does this, I end up with this :

```py
def get_mobile():
    """
    The Gateway's IDENTIFY packet contains a properties field, containing $os, $browser and $device fields.
    Discord uses that information to know when your phone client and only your phone client has connected to Discord,
    from there they send the extended presence object.
    The exact field that is checked is the $browser field. If it's set to Discord Android on desktop,
    the mobile indicator is is triggered by the desktop client. If it's set to Discord Client on mobile,
    the mobile indicator is not triggered by the mobile client.
    The specific values for the $os, $browser, and $device fields are can change from time to time.
    """
    import ast
    import inspect
    import re
    import discord

    def source(o):
        s = inspect.getsource(o).split("\n")
        indent = len(s[0]) - len(s[0].lstrip())

        return "\n".join(i[indent:] for i in s)

    source_ = source(discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify)
    patched = re.sub(
        r'([\'"]\$browser[\'"]:\s?[\'"]).+([\'"])',
        r"\1Discord Android\2",
        source_,
    )

    loc = {}
    exec(compile(ast.parse(patched), "<string>", "exec"), discord.gateway.__dict__, loc)
    return loc["identify"]
```

Now all there is left to do is overwrite the `discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify` during runtime in the main file, something like this :

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import mobile_status

discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify = mobile_status.get_mobile()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

And we do get the mobile status successfully 
[image: successful mobile status for bot]

**But here's the problem**, I wanted to directly modify the file (which held the function) rather than monkey-patching it during runtime. So I cloned the dpy lib locally and edited the file on my machine, it ended up looking like this :

```py
    async def identify(self):
        """Sends the IDENTIFY packet."""
        payload = {
            'op': self.IDENTIFY,
            'd': {
                'token': self.token,
                'properties': {
                    '$os': sys.platform,
                    '$browser': 'Discord Android',
                    '$device': 'Discord Android',
                    '$referrer': '',
                    '$referring_domain': ''
                },
                'compress': True,
                'large_threshold': 250,
                'v': 3
            }
        }
     # ...
```

(edited both `$browser` and `$device` to `Discord Android` just to be safe)

But this does not work and just gives me the regular desktop online icon.
So the next thing I did is to inspect the `identify` function *after* it has been monkey-patched, so I could just look at the source code and see what went wrong earlier, but due to hard luck I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Achxy\Desktop\fresh\file.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(inspect.getsource(discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify))
  File "C:\Users\Achxy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1024, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Users\Achxy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Users\Achxy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 835, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
```

Code :

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import mobile_status
import inspect

discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify = mobile_status.get_mobile()
print(inspect.getsource(discord.gateway.DiscordWebSocket.identify))
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Since this same behavior was exhibited for every patched function (aforementioned one and the `loc["identify"]`) I could no longer use `inspect.getsource(...)` and then relied upon `dis.dis` which lead to much more disappointing results

The disassembled data looks exactly identical to the monkey-patched working version, so the directly modified version simply does not work despite function content being the exact same. (In regards to disassembled data)

Notes: Doing `Discord iOS` directly does not work either, changing the `$device` to some other value but keeping `$browser` does not work, I have tried all combinations, none of them work.

TL;DR: How to get mobile status for discord bot without monkey-patching it during runtime?

Comment: That's odd, changing the dpy lib files directly for the IDENTIFY payload works for me. I used the exact same payload. I know this might be a dumb question, but: are you modifying the right file? For example, are you using a venv, but modifying the lib file in your global environment?

Comment: I have made sure I am acting on the correct file, @TheFungusAmongUs.

Comment: Are you sure the actual changed file is being used? Maybe add a debug statement `print("something")` inside. You might have multiple Python versions installed, and edited one, while running the other.

Comment: "*So I cloned the dpy lib locally*" If you meant you did `git clone`, then you're certainly acting on the wrong file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works by subclassing the relevant class, and duplicating code with the relevant changes. We also have to subclass the `Client` class, to overwrite the place where the gateway/websocket class is used. This results in a lot of duplicated code, however it does work, and requires neither dirty monkey-patching nor editing the library source code.

However, it does come with many of the same problems as editing the library source code - mainly that as the library is updated, this code will become out of date (if you're using the archived and obsolete version of the library, you have bigger problems instead).

```py
import asyncio
import sys

import aiohttp

import discord
from discord.gateway import DiscordWebSocket, _log
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


class MyGateway(DiscordWebSocket):

    async def identify(self):
        payload = {
            'op': self.IDENTIFY,
            'd': {
                'token': self.token,
                'properties': {
                    '$os': sys.platform,
                    '$browser': 'Discord Android',
                    '$device': 'Discord Android',
                    '$referrer': '',
                    '$referring_domain': ''
                },
                'compress': True,
                'large_threshold': 250,
                'v': 3
            }
        }

        if self.shard_id is not None and self.shard_count is not None:
            payload['d']['shard'] = [self.shard_id, self.shard_count]

        state = self._connection
        if state._activity is not None or state._status is not None:
            payload['d']['presence'] = {
                'status': state._status,
                'game': state._activity,
                'since': 0,
                'afk': False
            }

        if state._intents is not None:
            payload['d']['intents'] = state._intents.value

        await self.call_hooks('before_identify', self.shard_id, initial=self._initial_identify)
        await self.send_as_json(payload)
        _log.info('Shard ID %s has sent the IDENTIFY payload.', self.shard_id)


class MyBot(Bot):

    async def connect(self, *, reconnect: bool = True) -> None:
        """|coro|

        Creates a websocket connection and lets the websocket listen
        to messages from Discord. This is a loop that runs the entire
        event system and miscellaneous aspects of the library. Control
        is not resumed until the WebSocket connection is terminated.

        Parameters
        -----------
        reconnect: :class:`bool`
            If we should attempt reconnecting, either due to internet
            failure or a specific failure on Discord's part. Certain
            disconnects that lead to bad state will not be handled (such as
            invalid sharding payloads or bad tokens).

        Raises
        -------
        :exc:`.GatewayNotFound`
            If the gateway to connect to Discord is not found. Usually if this
            is thrown then there is a Discord API outage.
        :exc:`.ConnectionClosed`
            The websocket connection has been terminated.
        """

        backoff = discord.client.ExponentialBackoff()
        ws_params = {
            'initial': True,
            'shard_id': self.shard_id,
        }
        while not self.is_closed():
            try:
                coro = MyGateway.from_client(self, **ws_params)
                self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
                ws_params['initial'] = False
                while True:
                    await self.ws.poll_event()
            except discord.client.ReconnectWebSocket as e:
                _log.info('Got a request to %s the websocket.', e.op)
                self.dispatch('disconnect')
                ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, resume=e.resume, session=self.ws.session_id)
                continue
            except (OSError,
                    discord.HTTPException,
                    discord.GatewayNotFound,
                    discord.ConnectionClosed,
                    aiohttp.ClientError,
                    asyncio.TimeoutError) as exc:

                self.dispatch('disconnect')
                if not reconnect:
                    await self.close()
                    if isinstance(exc, discord.ConnectionClosed) and exc.code == 1000:
                        # clean close, don't re-raise this
                        return
                    raise

                if self.is_closed():
                    return

                # If we get connection reset by peer then try to RESUME
                if isinstance(exc, OSError) and exc.errno in (54, 10054):
                    ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, initial=False, resume=True, session=self.ws.session_id)
                    continue

                # We should only get this when an unhandled close code happens,
                # such as a clean disconnect (1000) or a bad state (bad token, no sharding, etc)
                # sometimes, discord sends us 1000 for unknown reasons so we should reconnect
                # regardless and rely on is_closed instead
                if isinstance(exc, discord.ConnectionClosed):
                    if exc.code == 4014:
                        raise discord.PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
                    if exc.code != 1000:
                        await self.close()
                        raise

                retry = backoff.delay()
                _log.exception("Attempting a reconnect in %.2fs", retry)
                await asyncio.sleep(retry)
                # Always try to RESUME the connection
                # If the connection is not RESUME-able then the gateway will invalidate the session.
                # This is apparently what the official Discord client does.
                ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, resume=True, session=self.ws.session_id)


bot = MyBot(command_prefix="?")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

bot.run("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
```

Personally, I think that the following approach, which does include some runtime monkey-patching (but no AST manipulation) is cleaner for this purpose:

```py
import sys
from discord.gateway import DiscordWebSocket, _log
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


async def identify(self):
    payload = {
        'op': self.IDENTIFY,
        'd': {
            'token': self.token,
            'properties': {
                '$os': sys.platform,
                '$browser': 'Discord Android',
                '$device': 'Discord Android',
                '$referrer': '',
                '$referring_domain': ''
            },
            'compress': True,
            'large_threshold': 250,
            'v': 3
        }
    }

    if self.shard_id is not None and self.shard_count is not None:
        payload['d']['shard'] = [self.shard_id, self.shard_count]

    state = self._connection
    if state._activity is not None or state._status is not None:
        payload['d']['presence'] = {
            'status': state._status,
            'game': state._activity,
            'since': 0,
            'afk': False
        }

    if state._intents is not None:
        payload['d']['intents'] = state._intents.value

    await self.call_hooks('before_identify', self.shard_id, initial=self._initial_identify)
    await self.send_as_json(payload)
    _log.info('Shard ID %s has sent the IDENTIFY payload.', self.shard_id)


DiscordWebSocket.identify = identify
bot = Bot(command_prefix="?")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

bot.run("YOUR_DISCORD_TOKEN")
```

As to why editing the library source code did not work for you, I can only assume that you have edited the wrong copy of the file, as people have commented.

Comment: Since many people have commented on this, I definitely need to recheck if it's the correct copy of the file, thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 5):

`DiscordWebSocket.identify` is non-trivial and there is no supported way to override those fields.

A more maintainable alternative to copy-pasting 35* lines of code to modify 2 lines, is to subclass and then override `DiscordWebSocket.send_as_json` (4 lines of custom code), and patch the `classmethod` `DiscordWebSocket.from_client` to instantiate the subclass:

```py
import os

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.gateway import DiscordWebSocket


class MyDiscordWebSocket(DiscordWebSocket):

    async def send_as_json(self, data):
        if data.get('op') == self.IDENTIFY:
            if data.get('d', {}).get('properties', {}).get('$browser') is not None:
                data['d']['properties']['$browser'] = 'Discord Android'
                data['d']['properties']['$device'] = 'Discord Android'
        await super().send_as_json(data)


DiscordWebSocket.from_client = MyDiscordWebSocket.from_client
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

*39 lines in Pycord 1.7.3. By overriding, you get future updates usually without additional effort.